# Incorrect redirect to user profile details

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

If the user is a staff' member he will see the list of users and their profile details, in addition to his profile details. If not, he will see only his profile details.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("user_details", kwargs={"username":self.username})
```

**views.py**

```
def usersList(request):
    """
    The list of all users
    """
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        users_list = UserProfile.objects.all()
    elif request.user.is_staff:
        users_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(is_staff=False)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
    template = 'usermanager/users_list.html'
    context = {
        'users': users_list,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

def userDetails(request, username):
    """
    User details
    """
    user_details = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=username)

    template = 'usermanager/user_details.html'
    context = {
        'user_details': user_details,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('user-list/', views.usersList, name='users'),
path('<username>/', views.userDetails, name='user_details'),
```

**users_list.html**

```
  {% for user in users %}
  <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
  <p>Name: {{ user.first_name }}</p>
  <p>Surname: {{ user.last_name }}</p>
  <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
  {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    {% if user.is_staff %}
    <button class="btn btn-warning">Staff</button>
    {% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary">User</button>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'user_details' username=user.username %}">Details</a>
  <hr>
  {% endfor %}
```

**user_details.html**

```
{% if request.user == user %}
<h1>Your profile</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>Profile of {{ user.username }}</h1>
{% endif %}
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <p>Name: {{ user.first_name }}</p>
  <p>Surname: {{ user.last_name }}</p>
  <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
  {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    {% if user.is_staff %}
    <button class="btn btn-warning">Staff</button>
    {% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary">User</button>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <p>Joined: {{ user.date_joined }}</p>
  <p>Last login: {{ user.last_login }}</p>
  {% if user.is_active %}
  <button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
  {% else %}
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">Inactive</button>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

I can see correctly the list of all users. *Bob* is one of my user, if I click on his details I see my personal profile. This happen for all of users details, I see always my profile. I'm logged in as superuser.

What I've wrong?

Comment: can you show us the user_details template? you are asking to see why your user_details page is showing a wrong information but we don't have the code to check. It seems that besides that, everything in your code is right.

In any case, are you using `{{ user_details.attribute }}` to show the information, or `{{ request.user.attribute }}` ?

Comment: I've do this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object for the user_Details is `{{user_details}}`, so you should be using that as a variable on the template:

`{% if request.user == user_details %}` and so on. That should solve your problem.

But as explained [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates), the template variable `user` is already used by Django to let you see the actual user information.

In your user list template you don't have this problem because you are overriding the `user` variable with the `for`.

Another recommendation is: Evade overriding the `user` variable on a template. for example on your users_list:

```
{% for usr in users %}
    <h1>{{ usr.username }}</h1>
    <p>Name: {{ usr.first_name }}</p>
    <p>Surname: {{ usr.last_name }}</p>
    <p>Email: {{ usr.email }}</p>
    {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
      {% if usr.is_staff %}
      <button class="btn btn-warning">Staff</button>
      {% else %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary">User</button>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'user_details' username=usr.username %}">Details</a>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my stupid error...
The contex of `userDetails` is `user_details` but I use `user` inside the template